# What is the proper way to spell "inspiraysh"?

Tags: orthography, abbreviations, pronunciation-vs-spelling, palatalization

I've noticed a trend among "younger people" to shorten words by simply cutting the ending off.

For example, instead of *inspiration* they might say something like *inspiraysh*.

What is the proper way (if there is one) of spelling such shortened words?

**Edit:** It seems to me that the natural thing to do would be removing the last few letters: i.e. the spelling *inspiraysh* would make perfect sense to me if the original word was *inspirayshon*. But in case of *inspiration* this is not an option, since it would alter the pronunciation.

Comment: They're probably saying inspire-ish. The suffix -ish means of or relating to. Like girlish, childish.

Comment: @JLG No, if it's a shortened noun I think it *isn't* -ish (an adjective)

Comment: I think he means like "vacay" for *vacation*.

Comment: @KitFox: By extension, then, if a "-tion" word is shortened by saying the leading "sh" in place of _-tion_ or _-tious_, how would you spell it? I don't know if I have 'nuff ambish to answer this q (although it seems pretty straightforward when the vowel sound is short).

Comment: @KitFox Or "Soshe" for "Soc" in The Outsiders. I kept pronouncing it "sock" because I didn't feel like it was right.

Comment: ***"delish"*** for ***"delicous"*** is an example I'm familiar with - it seems to be simply representing the sound (sh) without regard for the original word's spelling.

Comment: It is ironic that you should ask for a proper way to do something that is itself an improperly done thing: there can be no correct answer here.

Comment: Adding to Joe's and Kristina's examples, here's a closely related question: [How do I spell the truncation 'Cas', as in 'Sports Casual/Sports Cas'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/32403/how-do-i-spell-the-truncation-cas-as-in-sports-casual-sports-cas)

Comment: @tchrist: That's why I said "if there is one". Sometimes when something improper like this is used a lot, it becomes "standardized". Hence, the question. Also, it can be argued that all language begins as improper and only later certain forms become standardized by consistent use.

Comment: The correct way to write it is /ɪnspə'reʃ/, with a stressed final syllable. Of course, there's no unambiguous way to spell /reʃ/ in English orthography, so every group that wants to develops their own ingroupy way to do it.

Comment: Short answer: DON'T Longer answer: Why should every vocal utterance be rendered in writing? Some "younger people" make all sorts of noises that ought not appear in print. It will only encourage them!

Comment: But anything anyone says may need to be represented in print. If we want to represent these "shortenings," then, I believe the only reasonable way to do it is to redesign the spelling of the truncated ending, as in Kristina Lopez's example above, to be most likely to be read in such a way as to represent the sound that the speaker is using. @RegDwighт, then, I think your example might well be spelled "cazh."

Comment: To someone from [Kiritimati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiritimati) (originally *Christmas Island*) in [Kiribati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiribati) (originally *Gilberts*), the obvious spelling would be *inspirati* or perhaps *intibirati*

Answer (score 2):

If it's not a standard word, there's no standard way to spell it. I would spell it as it sounds (inspiraysh) because just chopping off letters would be confusing. (The usual caveats about not using it at all in a formal context and explaining it if necessary apply, but if I'd already considered that and decided I really did want to use this bit of slang, I would spell it exactly as it's pronounced.)